# Chrome doesn't display text-shadow with a spread value

Tags: google-chrome, rendering, css

I have this extremely simple HTML document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black">
            This should have a text shadow.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in Chrome 12.0.742.0 (latest dev version) the text-shadow does not display at all - it looks just like normal text. If you remove the third parameter (spread) it will render, but this is useless most of the time when you don't want a 1-pixel non-blurred shadow. How do I get it to display properly? I thought my syntax might be wrong but I don't think so because only some of the shadows on this page are shown in Chrome: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.

Comment: Works fine in the latest v11 beta. Maybe it's a v12 bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yea, I just updated to 12.0.742.0 and noticed the shadow disappeared from my website. I'm not going to worry about it unless it stays gone in future Chrome releases.

Answer (score 2):

Taken note of on the [Chromium bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80143).  I commented and linked back here. It is indeed a regression. Your CSS3 is valid.